# my web page's relative file path needs to changed when uploading local copy to bluehost

Tags: html, subdomain, local, relative-path

My relative file links in my web page need to be specified differently on my local copy vs web hosted copy

locally, i work in *MacHD/Library/WebServer/devapp* and I specify my relative css link in the *.../WebServer/devapp/index.php* file as:

`href = "/devapp/css/myStyle.css"`

When I upload my page to Bluehost in *home/public_html/devapp* the relative links don't load until I specify as:

`href = "/css/myStyle.css"`

neither href relative path works on both local/web host versions.

What can I do to achieve consistent behaviour across both?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this in pure HTML is to use the `<base href="…">` element like so:

```
<base href="/devapp/" />
```

Then you can use your relative css link like
`href = "./css/myStyle.css"`

Comment: hmm, adding <base href="/devapp/" /> works fine on the hosted version, but if i add it on my local it doesn't change any behaviour... the css file still needs me to specify /devapp/css/myStyle.css. It's looking like it's my local version that has peculiar behaviour.

Comment: Try with  `./css/myStyle.css`